# Trying to download a file using curl where file download is blocked by javascript?

Tags: php, file, curl

I am trying to use curl to download a torrent file the url is

http://torcache.net/torrent/006DDC8C407ACCDAF810BCFF41E77299A373296A.torrent

You will notice that upon getting to the page the download of the file is blocked for a few seconds via javascript, I was wondering if there is anyway to bypass this while using curl and php?

Thanks

Comment: Use Firebug (Firefox) to see the requests being sent out and duplicate it. Or Developer Tools if you are using Chrome/Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is not blocked via javascript, that's just an informal message if you request that file. The redirect then is done via javascript.

You can simulate the request your own, the important part here is that you add the HTTP Referrer request header. Example:

```
$ curl -I -H 'Referer: http://torcache.net/torrent/006DDC8C407ACCDAF810BCFF41E77299A373296A.torrent' http://torcache.net/torrent/006DDC8C407ACCDAF810BCFF41E77299A373296A.torrent
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.3.0
Date: Sun, 10 Jun 2012 17:13:59 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent
Content-Length: 10767
Last-Modified: Sat, 09 Jun 2012 22:17:03 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Referrer is one thing to check, mind the typo in the HTTP specs, see Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks this is awesome :) will try and convert it now to php code and get it to work :)